# PHP and SQL Server Express to retrieve and show data

Tags: php, sql

I am looking to take a PHP page to retrieve data based on the selection from a drop down list, then show the results based on that selection.  I am not even sure where to begin except my connection to the database.  I do also know that I have to have a query statement, like I would in SQL, which here is a little bit of that:

```
$sql = "SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes, Date
FROM   cslogs.dbo.Logs
WHERE  ForteID = 'bs1441'";
```

The bs1441 is just an example of one option that would be in the drop down list.  I am not sure what I would put there for it to put in there automatically from the list.

Thanks for the help in advance.  Sorry if there is not enough information to go on, but not sure what even would be needed at this point.

EDIT:

This is what I have so far:

```
<form method="get" action="getlog.php"> 

<table width="300" border="0">
<tr>
<td> Forte ID:</td>
<td><select id="ForteID" name="ForteID">                    
                <option value="nc4682">nc4682</option>
                <option value="bs1441">bs1441</option>
                <option value="sp3212">sp3212</option>                 
    </select></td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="getLog" value="Get Log">
</form> 
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$serverName = 'SRB-Nick_Desktop\SQLEXPRESS';
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'cslogs', 'UID'=>'cslogslogin', 'PWD'=>'123456');
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$result = sqlsrv_query( $connection, 
                'SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes, Date
                FROM    Logs
                WHERE   (ForteID = $ForteID)', 
                   array($ForteID));

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
echo($row['ForteID'] . ', '.
     $row['Disposition'] . ', '.
     $row['appNumber'] . ', '.
     $row['Finance_Num'] . ', '.
     $row['Num_Payments'] . ', '.
     $row['ACH_CC'] . ', '.
     $row['Notes'] . ', '.
     $row['Date']);
}
sqlsrv_close( $connection);
?>
```

Then when I look at the page it throws this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\cslogs\getlog.php on line 46

Line 46 is this line:

```
    echo($row['ForteID'] . ', '.
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: You should probably read [some documentation on MSSQL in PHP](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php).

Comment: Don't use sqlsrv_ functions. Not only do they not currently exist in a PHP release, they will *only* work if a specific configuration of SQL server is running on the same machine as PHP.

Answer (score 2):

A couple steps here:
First you need to submit your form with the selection in. I'm not going to go over form submission here but look into it.

once you submit the form you will need to get the value of the drop down and assign it to a variable.

```
$value= $_POST['value'];
```

Note: This is a basic example so I didnt add in regex or anything like that.

Once you have your variable ($value) you can then put it in your SQL

```
$sql = mssql_query($dbc,"SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC,    Notes, Date
FROM   cslogs.dbo.Logs
WHERE  ForteID = '$value'") or die("Query Error " . mssql_get_last_message());
```

So here we are processing the query. $dbc is the variable that I chose to represent my database connection and the "or die" part will let me know if the query is valid or not.

Once you have a working query you can then summon the data pulled into an array:

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($sql)) {
```

And then you need to assign the results of your query to a variable.

```
$result1 = $row["RESULT1"];
$result2 = $row["RESULT2"];
```

The capital words are the titles of the columns in your sql table. After you have them assigned to variables you can do whatever you want to them provided they are inside the while loop.

```
$value= $_POST['value'];

$sql = mssql_query($dbc,"SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC,    Notes, Date
FROM   cslogs.dbo.Logs
WHERE  ForteID = '$value'") or die("Query Error " . mssql_get_last_message());

while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $result1 = $row["RESULT1"];
    $result2 = $row["RESULT2"];

    echo $result1;
    echo $result2;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, except he isn't using mySQL. He's using MSSQL.

Comment: Thank you Sammitch looking back at his question i see that now. But, correct me if I am wrong it should be very similar. Just replace mysqli with mssql? I do not use mssql but I just checked php and the syntax looks the same? I guess the real goal here was to get him on the right thought path.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. However, in practice using MSSQL outside of an MS sandbox like .NET is never as easy as it logically should be.

Comment: True, I've updated it to reflect mssql but Sammitch is right.

Comment: I have made an edit above to my question.  If you can read that and see what is wrong.  When I made my post page, the mssql commands did not work, which I had help on that as well from this forum(thanks for the help again!)

Comment: I would recommend trying it one row at a time. And see where the error is. If you can just print 'echo $row[ForteID'] ' and make sure your query is pulling then you can try adding another line and glass-box test it from there

Comment: Well I figured out I missed an apostrophe to close out the query statement.  Then came a new error, think I fixed that.  Now I get this:  sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\cslogs\getlog.php on line 44.  Which is this line:  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result));

Comment: Make sure your query is valid. That error usually means that there is something wrong in your sql and it is returning a FALSE boolean

Comment: Well I am not even sure that the coding I am using is right. haha. It seems like I am missing something, but without really knowing code it is hard to even place what it is.

Comment: If you are new to code then I would suggest doing research into basic query composition. I know it sucks having someone tell you to do research but I promise you, if you start from the bottom and learn your way up you will be 100x better than if people just explain it. It regards to your question I can't test this but I would try taking the () off of (ForteID = $ForteID).

Comment: Yea I understand on researching this.  It is just so hard to learn this code, when everything that I have researched for the code says this is the code.  Then there is no preview of the example for me to learn, on what does what.  I guess it is hard to provide an example, but I will keep playing with it and see what happens.  Thanks again!